# 80s sci-fi book about a space spy with amnesia and a sentient watch

Tags: story-identification, novel

In late 80s as a 10/11 year old boy I got a book, the title of which I am now searching. It may have been a young adult/youth book or adult novel. Here it goes:

An astronaut/space soldier/spy wakes up with amnesia or some sort of confusion/lost memory. He has some sort of watch that is like a computer watch/sentience that he uses to help solve his mystery. It may have been set on Earth or another planet.

The cover from memory had a typical 80s style about it. It may have had a blue neon grid and a picture of the watch on cover.It may have been written in late 80s and I got it as it was a new book or possibly written much earlier.

Long shot, but wonder if anyone has any suggestions? I don't think it was a 'famous' or well known book or from famous author but I could be wrong.

Comment: There is a Dr. Who episode where he puts some part of himself into a watch and conceals himself as a human; he can become a Time Lord again via the watch.  He didn't wake up with amnesia though; he did it on purpose to hide from a predator.  Does this ring any bells?  It was an adaptation from a Dr. Who novel.

Comment: hey there. thanks for reply. no defs not Dr Who. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like "Memory Blank" by John Stith. The protagonist wakes and realises he's on a space station having lost several years of memory. He has an AI watch with which he tries to work out what happened.

Some of what he's forgotten is rather significant - he discovers that the population of Atlanta is now zero. As is the population of the planet Earth.